# Why is the internal pressure against the nozzle body not included in calculating the anchor force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image: Free Body Diagram]

Why is the internal pressure against the nozzle body not included in calculating the anchor force?  The attached picture shows all of the forces acting on the body.  But I would assume the pressure on the angled walls of the nozzle would cause a force in the downward direction of F= Pressure * sin(wall angle) * area.  From all examples of this nothing I can nothing factors this in and I do not fully understand why.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The figure shows the forces acting on the **fluid**, not on the nozzle body.  The anchoring force is what the nozzle has to exert on the fluid to satisfy the macroscopic momentum balance **on the fluid**.  This force is equal and opposite to the force the fluid exerts on the nozzle, and automatically includes the pressure the fluid exerts on the nozzle.

Comment: thanks for the reply! If the force is equal and opposite wouldn't the opposite force from the nozzle onto the fluid get transferred to the anchor?

Comment: The fluid ism’t attached to the anchor.  Only the nozzle is (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: The instructions for the problem state "The anchoring force sought is the reaction between the faucet and the nozzle threads".  You said the anchoring force is "what the nozzle has to exert on the fluid".  Shouldn't the force from pressure in the X direction be included in that calculation.  Apologies for leaving out the full description.

Comment: Here's how it plays out.  The nozzle exerts a force on the fluid.  This is what we are solving for with the macroscopic momentum balance (on the fluid within the control volume).  The fluid exerts an equal and opposite force on the nozzle (by Newton's third law).  This equal and opposite force automatically includes the fluid pressure force on the nozzle in the x direction.  From a force balance on the nozzle, the force that the fluid exerts on the nozzle is equal to the anchoring force (since the nozzle is in equilibrium).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine for simplicity that the nozzle is closed.

What force is exerted on the nozzle by the water?

It is the weight of the water, $W_w$, plus the pressure force $p_1A_1$. That's it.

There is no additional force $F$ acting on the angled wall - it is just a fraction of the combined force we've identified, applied to the wall. The rest of the combined force will be applied to the closed bottom of the nozzle. If the nozzle was replaced by a cone $(A_2=0)$, all combined force would be applied to its wall.

Answer (score 0):

The exit conditions are given here, which are actually dictated by the shape of the nozzle, hence when you are calculating the anchor force from inlet and exit conditions, the influence of nozzle shape is already considered.